# How to change color of a layer in ArcGIS Javascript API by accessing the layer object?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to change layer color with every click of a button. So far I have been able to do lots working with the layer object alone, for example `schools= this.map.getLayer("schools")`. However, there are no methods for dealing with the symbology on the layer object.

I've seen [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/fillsymbol-amd.html) for changing symbology of *graphics* layers, however. But I'm not sure how to implement that from where I am now. How do I reference a graphics layer from my layer and access the fill methods? Or am I misunderstanding these objects to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a renderer.

Use this example provided by ESRI:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/renderer_legend.html

Here is a fiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/kreza/g9omqj3j/54/

Might need to pan to get items to refresh but it should get you going.